# Equilibrium between two water tanks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, water, viscosity, bernoulli-equation

I've been reading about hydrostatic theory, however I couldn't find a similar case/exercise about my basic problem.

I have two water tanks (same size) filled with different water heights, and connected themselves with a little pipe at the bottom of each.

How could I calculate the time to reach equilibrium?

Comment: Dynamics is wildly more complicated than statics.  For the question *how long will the tanks take to equilibrate*, consider if the fluid was very thick, sticky honey: interactions between the honey and tube (as well as within the honey, including the temperature of everything) would play a factor for how long it takes to equilibrate.  Now consider an ideal fluid: there would never be equilibrium since it would just slosh back and forth forever.  Moral: you need a lot more information about the system to *calculate* the time an actual, physical setup like you describe would take to stop moving.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could consider that the size of the bottom pipe is much smaller than the size of the tanks, so that the water height will change very slowly and you can apply Bernoulli's principle at both ends of the connecting pipe using the hydrostatic pressure, that will give you the speed of the flow and then you could use the continuity equation, but the problem is that you need to know the ratio of the pipe size to the tank size. Maybe theres another way to do it but i can't figure it right now.

Comment: I have all the measures. I've looked at [this applet] (http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/fluidos/dinamica/oscilaciones/oscilaciones.htm), however it seems to oscillate indefinately at the same speed and never stops.

Comment: Is there any (visual) software to perform these kind of calculations?

Comment: if you have ipython notebook, enter to nbviewer.ipython.org and paste the next url https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9449f6d08370d702b27a, download the notebook and play with it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. I know a little about phython so I'll try